# Do sections have technical role in Setup.ini answer files?

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, ini

We're working on automated deployment of MSI packages. This includes dynamically generating `setup.ini` answer files.

A sample `setup.ini` file contains several sections to group the variables like `[Database]`, etc. Are these sections only a semantic grouping to improve maintainability, or do they have any technical role? I mean will the installer work if I omit all the sections?

Currently unfortunately there is no easy way to just try it.

Answer (score 0):

Sections are somewhat like namespaces. So, in general, removing sections changes the semantic meaning of the file. It's unlikely to work correctly; two values with the same name in different sections are likely to be treated completely differently by the code that consumes them, which in turn requires their sections still be present.

But to answer for certain, I'd have to know what reads the ini file. Windows Installer doesn't do so by default, but a given package could be authored to do so. Similarly, the built-in support for it uses section names, but custom code (such as in a custom action) could read an ini file in a way that would let it work. Or could crash. Who knows?